# problem with moving prestashop from localhost to the server

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I created a shop on localhost (I added my own theme).

Then I moved to the server and I am getting the following error.

> [ThemeRepository] Theme configuration file not found for theme at
>   `//themes/DrewDom/config/theme.yml`.
>       at line 144 in file srcCoreAddonThemeThemeRepository.php

Answer (score 0):

This file `folder_ps/themes/DrewDom/config/theme.yml` exist on your server ?